# If dropdown value then show other cell [EXCEL]

Tags: excel

How to do the following in excel:
If dropdown value then show another cell.

So if Battery: PHS is selected, how do I get the value of 'Kosten per kWh', automatically updating the cell => 90.

[image]

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP()` to retrieve an individual item and use `AutoFilter` to retrieve the entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the data above as the base for something that's happening in another sheet. In this other sheet, you have a dropdown list (say, in cell A1) which uses your battery type as values, and you want that when one battery type is selected, the corresponding kosten per kw/h is shown in another cell (say, B1).

If that's the scenario, then yes, as Gary's Student suggested, in B1 put a `VLOOKUP()` that uses A1 as the key to search into your table above, and returns the value of column 10.